# Generate a street map image

Tags: ruby, google-maps, lua, openstreetmap

I'm working on redeveloping a script which plots game data on a generated street map image. The current solution is in R, but the API it is using is no longer working, and I am personally not familiar with R.

What I am looking for is a way to get an image of a certain area given longitude/latitude bounds in a language I am more familar with, such as Ruby or Lua. I've looked for a solution, but the Ruby packages (e.g. Google Maps for Rails) seem unfinished and often focussed on embedding a google map in a web page. The exact look of the map doesn't matter as much, as long as the street layout is recognizable to a local.

How can I automatically generate such a street map image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end you just need to download the relevant map [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). For OSM tile servers take a look at the [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames). It explains how to calculate the tile name based on lat, lon and zoom level. It also contains dozens of example implementations for various programming and scripting languages.

Also make sure to read the tile usage policy / terms of service for the tile server you have chosen.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to code this up using MiniMagick and the tile names. Not quite the single line solution we had before, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as this question didn't have any complete answers, I built a gem for doing just this.

https://gitlab.com/Qwertie/osm_tile_grabber

(Check the repo for the latest info but at the current time this is the gem usage)

```
require 'osm_tile_grabber'
osm = OSMTileGrabber.new(-34.9220585,138.5879188,-34.9397,138.6239,15)
osm.create_image("/tmp/output.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this static map helper GIST:

```
module StaticMapHelper

  def static_map_for(location, options = {})
    params = {
      :center => [location.lat, location.lng].join(","),
      :zoom => 15,
      :size => "300x300",
      :markers => [location.lat, location.lng].join(","),
      :sensor => true,
      :maptype => 'satellite',
      }.merge(options)

    query_string =  params.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
    image_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?#{query_string}", :alt => location.name
  end

end
```

https://gist.github.com/mcasimir/2778938